# Is it possible to replicate wide table in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, transactional-replication

The reason of me using sparse columns is to overcome limit of 1024 columns in a table (I know that generally it's not a good reason and there are [downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1398481/195446), but in my situation it's good option compared to software rewrite option and I didn't write that software, so [don't tell me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135739/195446) it's bad design, I know).

My customer uses transactional table replication for backup (which means they replicate whole table). So I wonder if replication will work after I start adding those extra sparse columns above 1024 limit.

So far I found 3 limits:

1) [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) says that I cannot replicate column sets.

2) [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) says that SQL Server snapshot or transactional publication limit is 1000 columns.

3) From my experiments I found that I cannot add more than 1024 sparse columns if I don't have column set defined.

From these 3 limits I conclude that I cannot replicate wide master table into wide slave table.
Is my conclusion correct ?

Is it possible to replicate non-wide parts of master row to combine into one wide row in slave table ? Non-wide I mean < 1000 columns.

If possible then how ? Are there any gotchas for replicating wide tables ?

Update:

4) It looks like [custom replication SP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152489.aspx) is one possible answer. Did anybody try to replicate more than 1000 columns with custom replication SPs ?

Comment: Can you use a XML column?  That will allow you unlimited extra fields in the XML DOM.

Comment: XML column will be my next possible choice, but I cannot index them and also cannot update them as separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a table into a wide table, you must create sparse columns and also add a column set. If you don't create a column set your table will still be limited to 1024 columns. This is why you can't use replication for wide tables.

Comment: I agree. I've tried and could not even add wide table using sp_addarticle with , @vertical_partition = N'true'. It's also not allowed to add it MS SQL Studio UI.